# Raspberry Pi isn't connected as a remote debugger?

Tags: pi-2, windows-iot, c#

I can no longer deploy my app to my raspberry pi as it wont recognize it as a remote debugger . It was working the day before and now it has stopped and I do not know why. It has the windows 10 iot core and I am using visual studio to code for it . Any help will be greatly appreciated . Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have actually solved this . I used the device portal associated with the Iot dashboard and started the debugger from within the processes there . I then had to change the debug settings for the remote machine name to the complete ip and port number provided when you start the debugger from the dashboard and it is now working again.